# "Double Load" Issue with PHP isset() and $_POST data

Tags: php, html, forms, post, isset

I know I am doing something wrong by using a combination of isset(), $_POST and $_GET but I am wondering what would be the easiest and painless way to tackle my issue.

The issue arises when I submit a HTML form... It reloads the page with the post data. I capture the submit with a php isset() function, process the $_POST data and then run a window.location to refresh the page with some $_GET data.

For example...

```
//example.php
...

<form action="" method="post">

  <input name="stage1name" type="text" class="textfield" size="22" value="<?php echo $ClaimRow['ClaimantName']; ?>">
  <input name="VehicleEngine" type="text" class="textfield" size="20" value="<?php echo $vehiclerow['VehicleEngine']; ?>">
  <input name="VehicleFuel" type="text" class="textfield" size="20" value="<?php echo $vehiclerow['VehicleFuel']; ?>">

  <input name="submitInfo" type="submit" value="<?php echo $LANG_Claims_Change_Info; ?>" />

</form>

...
<?php  

    if (isset($_POST['submitInfo']))
    { 
        $stage1name= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['stage1name']);
        $VehicleEngine= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['VehicleEngine']);
        $VehicleFuel= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['VehicleFuel']);
        mysqli_query($db, "DO SOME COOL SQL HERE");

        //I've done what I need to do so lets reload the page with the updated data

        echo "<script>window.location='example.php?vehicle=" . $vehicleID . "&claimTab=Personal'</script>";

    }
?>
```

Like I said before, this method works fine however the user gets the effect of a "double load" and is very epiletic fit inducing.

Any ideas how best to combat this?

Thanks

**EDIT - Additional Example**

I realised that this one example might not make complete sense so I put together another example which hopefully will.

```
...

<form action="" method="post">  
    <select name="addresstype[]" id="multiselectfrom" onchange='this.form.submit();' size="9" style="width:110px; text-align:center;">
        <option style="<?php if ($AddType == 'Claimant') { echo'background-color:#9AD3F1 !important;'; } ?>" value="Claimant"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Claimant; ?></option>
        <option style="<?php if ($AddType == 'Vehicle') { echo'background-color:#9AD3F1 !important;'; } ?>" value="Vehicle"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Vehicle; ?></option>
        <option style="<?php if ($AddType == 'Repairer') { echo'background-color:#9AD3F1 !important;'; } ?>" value="Repairer"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Repairer; ?></option>
        <option style="<?php if ($AddType == 'Insurer') { echo'background-color:#9AD3F1 !important;'; } ?>" value="Insurer"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Insurer; ?></option>
        <option style="<?php if ($AddType == 'Fleet') { echo'background-color:#9AD3F1 !important;'; } ?>" value="Fleet"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Fleet; ?></option>
    </select>
</form>

...

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['addresstype']))
    { 
        foreach ($_POST['addresstype'] as $addresstype) {
            $addresstype2 = $addresstype;
        }
        echo "<script>window.location='claims.php?claimID=" . $claim . "&claimTab=Addresses&AddressType=" . $addresstype2 . "'</script>";
    }
?>
```

The above example is supposed to take the result of the form and change the window.location depending on the form result. It does work however it loads the page twice in doing so.

Comment: `header('Location: example.php?vehicle=' . $vehicleID . '&claimTab=Personal'); `   then `die();`

Comment: you are again sending data on the same page `example.php` and i didn't see any use of sending values in the parameter in form of query string.

Comment: adding die(); after window.location doesn't do anything as it's already killed it self off. 

A-2-A I believe my example isn't a very good one. I will post another example and maybe it would make more sense.

Comment: why you not use ajax jquery ?

Comment: can you provide an example? I use ajax for some table stuff but I am not 100% with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing. It turns out CMorriesy was correct. However for future reference you will need to turn `output_buffering = on` in php.ini and also add `<?php ob_start(); ?>` to the very first line of your code.

`header('Location: example.php?vehicle=' . $vehicleID . '&claimTab=Personal'); die();`

Answer (score 0):

Repalace:

```
echo "<script>window.location='example.php?vehicle=" . $vehicleID . "&claimTab=Personal'</script>";
```

With:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV = 'Refresh' Content = '0; URL =example.php?vehicle=" . $vehicleID . "&claimTab=Personal'>";
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. In cases where it would be applicable it still "double loads" and in cases where I try to pass the form result i.e. in the additional example it doesn't pass the extra value, it just refreshes.